# Submitting array to Spring controller

Tags: ajax, json, spring, jquery

I am trying to submit checkbox's values array to controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(@RequestBody UserForm form, HttpServletResponse response) { ... }
```

where UserForm has:

```
public class UserForm extends BaseForm {    
     private String[] role; ... }
```

I post with jquery's postJSON method. Everything fine when there are more then one selected checkbox - controller successfully translated it to array of String. But in case of only single checkbox is selected - serversife fails because the request parameters (especcially role field) has been passed as string and not array with single value.
The checkboxes looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="2" />
etc...
```

Any help? Thank you

Additional:

```
$.postJSON(url + 'save',
                $('#userForm').serializeObject(),
                function(response) {
                    if (response.isAuthenticated && response.isAuthorized) {
                        if (response.hasErrors) {
                            $('#userForm').setErrors(response.errors);
                            hideWait();
                        }
                        else 
                            $('#filter').click();
                    }
                    else
                        redirectToLogin();
                });
```

Comment: COuld you show the postJSON method plz? And could you plz accept a few more answers from your previous questions.

Comment: serializeObject() is the json's library method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found:

```
var data = $('#userForm').serializeObject();
        data.ur = new Array();
        $('#ur:checked').each(function() {
            data.ur.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.postJSON(url + 'save',
                data,
                function(response) {
                    if (response.isAuthenticated && response.isAuthorized) {
                        if (response.hasErrors) {
                            $('#userForm').setErrors(response.errors);
                            hideWait();
                        }
                        else 
                            showList(true);
                    }
                    else
                        redirectToLogin();
                });
```